# How to get all outputs that sql statements creates?

Tags: php, sql

This is my sql statement

```
SELECT TOWN_ID FROM TOWN WHERE CITY_ID = 1
```

output are :  4,5,6,7,67,887

In php my code is like this :

```
$temp = 1;
$sql = "SELECT TOWN_ID FROM TOWN WHERE CITY_ID = 1 = $temp";
$compiled = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_execute($compiled);
$row = oci_fetch_array($compiled, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_LOBS);
foreach ($row as $element ) 
{
  echo "\n".$element."\n";
}
```

My output is just 4 , how to get other outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-array.php): *Returns the next row from a query as an associative or numeric array*

You need to call this function in a loop to get all records:

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($compiled, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_LOBS))
{
  foreach ($row as $element ) 
  {
    echo "\n".$element."\n";
  }
}
```